# Digital image processing with MATLAB using 3 techniques

Tags: algorithm, image, matlab, image-processing

I have a homework in MATLAB. I must use 3 image processing techniques. So I should make a task and then solve it using 3 techniques(for example, thresholding, segmentation, morphology, restoration, histogram equalization, noise remove...). I need some idea and how to solve it, will you help me? :)

Thank you.

- **In edition:**

I have found this in some book....Do you have any idea? Is it possible to restore picture **a** to picture **i**?

**Note**: Some solution is indicated below.But to tell the truth I didn't understand :( Can you explain it to me?

[image: Solution??]

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't describe your assignment ...

Comment: I don't know how to explain... for example I have a picture, which can be found http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-2E/dip2e_book_images_downloads.htm  , and on this picture I should use three methods. For example if I have a noised image, I should remove a noise, this method is called noise removal...then I want to make thresholding to make this picture black&white... So I need clever steps...Something like not very simple task...

Did I explain well?

Comment: The mark on this homework very depends on the complexity of the task.

We were studying this lecture for 1 month(not a big period). So task should be neither simple nor very complex... It should be a middle level task or a little less.

Comment: Try the following. Look at some of the images in the database you linked, and see if you can think of some interesting tasks. List those tasks, and we'll try to help you by explaining some techniques which could be used to solve the task. We can also help by determining the difficulty level of the task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jacob. Please see the post, I've edited it.

Comment: @Jacob are you able to help me?

Comment: @kupa You first proposed a problem, then changed it, and finally accepted your own answer to a (third) completely different problem.

Comment: @belisarius I mentioned from the beginning that this was my homework and I had to think any problem and its solution... I was trying to find a good problem... I Discussed several variants and because of the first two variants were difficult to solve I changed them(Even you were not able to solve the task which is written above,this was the main reason why i left this) I am not experienced in this subject but after searching some methods,demos and so on...on the internet very good variant came to my mind and I wrote it... Deadline was till 18 March,so I was hurry...Sorry for disturbing you:(

Comment: @belisarius I really appreciate your help!!!!!

Comment: @kupa Don't apologize, as you are not doing anything "bad". It's just unusual. BTW. try to post here in SO your solved problem instead of just leaving a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restoration of this picture is very difficult... So I decided to change the task.

The task and solution are discussed here:

http://geogeeks.net/2011/03/18/digital-image-processing-using-matlab/

Answer (score 6):

### You could for example try to isolate an object by three different methods.

Let's do this in Mathematica. (MATLAB is *your* homework).

Let's call our image **i**:

**i =** [image]

And let's try to isolate a mask called **mask**:

**mask =** [image]

See the example codes:

```
(* First Method, by Image Correlation*)
x = ImageCorrelate[ i, mask, EuclideanDistance];
r = Position[ImageData@Binarize[x, 0.2], 0, Infinity];
(*Show that we found the right spot *)
ImageCompose[i, 
 ColorNegate@
  mask, {0, Dimensions[ImageData[i]][[1]]} - {-1, 1} Reverse[r[[1]]]]
```

Result:

[image]

```
(* Second method, separating channels, 
   thresholding and deleting small components*)

r = DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[#, .99] &@
   ColorNegate[ColorSeparate[i][[3]]];
ImageMultiply[i, r]
```

Result:

[image]

```
(* Third method, extracting the exact color *)
Image[ImageData[i] /. {1., 0.6, 0.} -> {a} /. {_, _, _} -> {0, 0,0} /. 
                                       {a} -> {1., 0.6, 0.}]
```

Result:

[image]

HTH!

Comment: Thank a lot @belisarius. Very good answer!!!... But to tell the truth, it is a little bit difficult for me(I didn't understand what the mask is picture or what...)... What do you think about my pictures? I have uploaded them. Can you make the 1st pic as the 3rd one is?

Thank you for that you have spend your valuable time on my problem...

Comment: @kupa Sorry, I answered before seeing your edit. I will give your images a try and see what I can come with.

Answer (score 4):

I am giving a try to the images you posted in the edit.  The results are not perfect, but this is an approximation. Finding the right filters may take a while.

First applying a Laplacian filter to remove noise, you get:

```
TotalVariationFilter[image, 1, Method -> "Laplacian"]
```

[image]

And then you have to deconvolve the diagonal motion blur. You need a kernel like this one :

[image]

Which, when applied to the de-noised image gives:

```
ImageDeconvolve[denoisedImage, kernel, Method -> "RichardsonLucy", 
 MaxIterations -> 15]
```

[image]

The image is not perfect, but I hope this gives you an idea of what can be done.

Comment: thank you a lot... It is a pretty good idea...I will take it into my mind...Let me wait till 17 March and if no one gives me the better solution, I will accept your answer. Thank you...

Comment: I have added something important in my post can you help me?