# correlation function in Opencv

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, cross-correlation

Help me to learn correlation function in Opencv.

I have read some references but I unable to get a correct idea. 
Using Correlation can I match two images and assign weights on them by considering relation between original and another. ?
(becouse I want to match 2 images like same but not 100% same)
Is a kind of Template matching ...?

I wonder if someone can point me a sample code in c++ somewhere in net.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image Correlation to find subimages inside an image.

This is how it works, looking for zeroes inside a textbox:

[image]

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302041/digital-image-processing-with-matlab-using-3-techniques/5303049#5303049)